# decrypting pdf protected by aes-256bit using the right password

Tags: python, pdf, command-line, aes

Is there any way to decrypting a pdf protected by an aes-256 bit key?

I have the correct password and I need a command-line tool (or library - perhaps in python :P ) for decrypting the file and then doing some operation over it.

The best thing could be if the file could be saved decrypted, then I elaborate it and then I can remove it...

Does anyone know something about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pyPdf                                                                
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open("file.pdf"))
pdf.decrypt("password")
```

You can then do whatever you want with the contents.  This will work with either the user or owner passwords.

Comment: however I can't decrypt pdf files made through adobe acrobat 6 or later

Comment: I found this so fat but couldn't find how to save the decryped pdf? 
Create a `pdfFileWriter` and write page by page? or Is there a better way?

Comment: You can always extract the contents and write it to any file type you wish.